# Alternative to iTunes for burning audio CD's

Tags: macos, software-rec, burning, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to burn mp3 files to a playable audio CD](https://superuser.com/questions/85523/how-to-burn-mp3-files-to-a-playable-audio-cd)
>   [Is there an easy way to copy an audio CD in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/106892/is-there-an-easy-way-to-copy-an-audio-cd-in-mac-os-x)

What software is good as an alternative to iTunes for burning audio CD's for use in a CD player?

Edit, forgot to mention that I am on Mac OS X.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) for OS X.
[CDBXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) for Windows (I must warn that I have not had much luck on Vista with this one, though it says its compatible).